# How can I make new column with dynamic values

Tags: excel

Id 
 1
 2
 3
 4
 2
 3
 3
 3

Questions 
create  one new column and that is  newid

output should be like this.

```
id  newid 

1 1
2 1
3 1
4 1
2 0
3 0
3 0
3 0
```

Please suggest me how can I do it and which formula to be used in excel

Comment: could you please clarify the question, as it is, it is hard to understand

Comment: Assuming you have a header row so that actual data starts in row 2, and that your `Id` column is column A, then in cell B2 and copied down: `=--(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A2)=0)`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following post and update the question appropriately:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask